# How to align <div class=container> in a message style format?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to reproduce a message thread format. One container that starts on the left side of the screen (incoming messages) and another container that starts on the right side of the screen (outgoing messages). Currently both containers are centered on the page and the text inside them is printing correctly (left side and right side respectively). I do not want the text position to change, only the container locations.
Ideally, I would like it to look like this:

```
         ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
         +Container                         +
         +                                  +
         ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

                                       ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                                       +                  Container darker+
                                       +                                  +
                                       ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Here is my code so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.darker {
  border-color: #000000;
  background-color: #0077ff;
  text-align: right
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Chat Messages</h2>

<div class="container">
<p>'(123)456-7890'</p>
<p>'Hello!'</p>
<p>'10/10/2022 @ 15:00:00'</p>
</div>

<div class="container darker">
<p>'(123)456-0987'</p>
<p>'Hi!'</p>
<p>'10/10/2022 @ 15:00:07'</p>
</div>

</body>\n
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set margins on the side where you want the space.

But you should use class names that describe *what* an element represents, not how it should look.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.message {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.outgoing {
  border-color: #000000;
  background-color: #0077ff;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.incoming {
  margin-right: 20%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Chat Messages</h2>

<div class="incoming message">
  <p>'(123)456-7890'</p>
  <p>'Hello!'</p>
  <p>'10/10/2022 @ 15:00:00'</p>
</div>

<div class="outgoing message">
  <p>'(123)456-0987'</p>
  <p>'Hi!'</p>
  <p>'10/10/2022 @ 15:00:07'</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked with a little tweaking of the margin percentages. I agree with you and changed the class names to what the do. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS flexbox with column direction on the parent element (in this case, I've created `div.wrapper`) and then use `align-self: flex-end` for the elements that you want flush right.

To ensure that the message is "shrink-wrapped", you can optionally use `width: fit-content` on top of specifying a max-width:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  max-width: 65%;
  width: fit-content;
}

.message.align-right {
  border-color: #000000;
  background-color: #0077ff;
  text-align: right;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="message">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sed pretium sem, et blandit quam.
  </div>
  <div class="message align-right">
    Sed et ullamcorper magna.
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    Nullam vulputate turpis lorem, id malesuada purus consectetur quis.
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    Phasellus mattis ante dolor, sit amet blandit enim rhoncus id.
  </div>
  <div class="message align-right">
    Aenean eu mauris ac sem blandit mollis. Praesent feugiat ex vel risus vulputate, vitae dictum ex posuere.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

- Wrap all containers in another div with a style (used the class `thread`)
- Define a width lower than 100% in container class
- Define `align-self` in darker class

```html
<head>
  <!-- ... -->
  <style>
    /* ... */
    .thread {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .container {
      /* ... */
      width: 80%;
    }
    .darker {
      /* ... */
      align-self: flex-end;
    }
    /* ... */
  </style>
  <!-- ... -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- ... -->
  <div class="thread">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <div class="container darker">
      <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</body>
```